# This generator (@microsoft/sharepoint:app) requires yeoman-environment at least 3.0.0, current version is 2.10.3

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

I am getting the following error when trying to use `yo @microsoft/sharepoint`

```
Error @microsoft/sharepoint

This generator (@microsoft/sharepoint:app) requires yeoman-environment at least 3.0.0, current version is 2.10.3, try reinstalling latest version of 'yo' or use '--ignore-version-check' option
```

I have reinstalled the lastest version and can see that the current and wanted version matches when I use the command `npm -g outdated`.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error, but in fact it seemed it came from the version of the generator-sharepoint that was not compatible.

try this :

```
npm uninstall -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint
```

then install a previous version :

```
npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.11.0
```

I put here the version I have to be able to create spfx solution (because I had a looot of trouble finding stuff that work together) :

Yo --version > 3.1.1

node -v > 10.24.0 (avoid 12 at all cost)

tsc -v > 4.0.5

note : to check your version of generator :

```
npm ls -g --depth=0 @microsoft/generator-sharepoint
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your yeoman package is outdated. Try the following command to get the latest version:

```
npm install yo@3.1.1 -g
```

**Update**

As of today, yeoman v4 is not compatible with the SPFx generator. this is why we install v3.

Comment: I get `TypeError: lookups.flatMap` is not a function" error when using `yo @microsoft/sharepoint` once i update it

Comment: updated the answer. I forgot that yo v4 causes this issue. Try installing v3. It will fix it.

Comment: Hi @denis-molodtsov, thank you for your help. I tried it but it just wouldn't work so I decided to just uninstall everything and reinstall it following the steps here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment

Comment: Good point. Perhaps, you also had other issues. For example, with the wrong node.js version

Answer (score 0):

check your version list---

- npm ls -g --depth=0

try this :

1. npm uninstall -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint

then install a previous version :

2. npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.11.0